# How to send traffic to CloudFront host using tsung

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, load-testing, tsung

How to send traffic to CloudFront host using tsung? Tsung mandates port number for sending traffic, but CloudFront doesn't have one.
If we using host:port to send traffic, CloudFront is rejecting that traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working tsung config for CloudFront traffic test. (Tsung version 1.6.1_git) I hope this will help you. But keep in mind that CloudFront has advanced DDoS protection.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/usr/local/share/tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd" [] >
<tsung loglevel="info" dumptraffic="true">
    <clients>
        <client host="t1" maxusers="5000" cpu="4">
        </client>
    </clients>

    <servers>
        <server host="[YOUR.CF.SUBDOMAIN].cloudfront.net" port="80" type="tcp"></server>
    </servers>

     <load>
         <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="10" unit="second">
             <users interarrival="1" unit="second"></users>
         </arrivalphase>
     </load>

    <sessions>
        <session name='cloudfront' probability='100'  type='ts_http'>
            <request>
                <http url='/65.png' version='1.1' method='GET' />
            </request>
        </session>
    </sessions>
</tsung>
```

You need an ip record in your ***host*** file. ***t1*** in this case.
(Unix: `/etc/hosts`, MS: `windows/system32/drivers/etc/host`)

```
[YOU_IP_ADDRESS]    t1
```